# Model pack material colours are all wrong

Tags: color

New to blender. Recently purchased a model pack that contains several pre-made buildings. However, when I open the blend file. All the colours look wrong across all view port modes. For example, in this image, the trees are brown. When I open up the material properties - they assigned to a colour "green".

[image]

This is in viewport solid mode - if I were to select render view, everything is a dark pink:

[image]

Here is a look at my material panel when I have a "brown" plane selected:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pink color usually means that the corresponding images were not found. Seems like the textures are not packed into the .blend file and you should manually set up all necessary links.

If you've downloaded an archive with bunch of files, try to find textures there. If there're not any textures… Talk to the creator of the pack and never buy anything from him.

Comment: Yep spot on - there were several download files - the textures were in a directory for a different 3D software - moved them over and it's working fine!!! Thanks!